# SQL Server Remote Connections

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been through the settings a hundred times and to no avail, I can not get remotely connected to a SQL Server on my network. I have two SQL Servers on different machines. I can connect to one, but not the other. As far as I can tell, all the server properties and server configurations are identical.

I have all firewalls turned off completely. I've even googled for how to do this because at this point I feel like a completely lost noob. I can ping and communicate with the remote machine. Just can't see the SQL Server.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/

I've done all that. Yes, I'm using 2008 R2, as that's the supported server by the software manufacturer that I'm exchanging data with.

What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: Whats the exact error message?  Is this the default instance?  It might be a port issue...

Comment: Frequently I've found that everything looks configured correctly, except SQL Server isn't actually listening on the IP address you are trying to connect on.  That seems to be skipped in your linked article.  Try running `netstat -nab -p TCP` from the command prompt on the SQL Server and make sure your server is listening on the IP/Port you expect.

Answer (score 1):

My first step is to check is the TCP/IP is enabled for the instance of the SQL server you want to connect too.

The next thing to try is telnet to the server: telnet SERVER.IP.ADDRESS 1433

[This article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/827422) is helpful

[image: SQL Server TCP/IP]

More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: You linked what I linked?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see and connect after adding Outbound UDP 1434 to my exceptions.